# Enviar varios datos con AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo esta lista donde muestro el resultado de una consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<tbody>
                  <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados INNER JOIN nomina ON nomina.codigoRac=empleados.codigoRac";
                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                      ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $row['codigoRac']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['apellido']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['mes']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['ano']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>
                          <td>
                    

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $row['codigoRac']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

                          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $row['codigoRac']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      <?php
                    }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
```

En cada button hay un data-id con el codigorac para enviarlo a la siguiente función para que me muestre el siguiente formulario:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#example1 tbody').on('click','.view', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#view').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var mes = $(this).data('mes');
    getRow(id);
  });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="view">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Nomina del Trabajador</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form class="form-horizontal" id="nomina_view" method="POST" action="">
                <h5 align="right"><b><i></i></b></h5>

                <div id="info">
                <span><b>Codigo Rac:</b> </span><span id="id_view"></span><br>
                <span><b>Nombre y Apellido: </b></span><span id="nombreapellido"></span><br>
                <span><b>Tipo: </b></span><span id="tipo"></span><br>
                <span><b>Cargo: </b></span><span id="cargo"></span><br>
                </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="codigorac" value="">
            </div>
        <div id="nomina"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cerrar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" id="nomina" name="add"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i> Listar</button>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Uso este código para enviar el codigorac a una consulta, y traerme los demas datos: tipo, cargo, etc

```js
function getRow(id){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'payroll_row.php',
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      $('#id').val(response.codigoRac);
      $('#id_view').html(response.codigoRac);
      $('#nombreapellido').html(response.nombre+' '+response.apellido);
      $('#tipo').html(response.tipo);
      $('#cargo').html(response.nombreCargo);
    }
  });
}
```

Consulta en PHP:

```
<?php 
include 'includes/session.php';

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados INNER JOIN estatus ON estatus.estatusId=empleados.estatusId INNER JOIN cargos ON cargos.cargoId=empleados.cargoId WHERE codigoRac = '$id'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();

    echo json_encode($row);
}?>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, lo que quiero es poder enviar el año y el mes (que muestro en la lista del principio) al PHP donde consulto, para poder traerme los registros que tengan esos dos campos (año y mes) y luego con el codigo AJAX asignar ese valor a un input

Comment: en la funcion getRow(id)?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, lo encontré en otro tema aparte, en el button agregue la funcion getRow con los valores que voy a enviar

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $row['codigoRac']; ?>" onclick="getRow($('#id').val(), $('#mes').val(), $('#ano').val());return false;" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Luego recibo los parametros en getRow:

```js
function getRow(id,mes,ano){
  var parametros = {
                "id" : id,
                "mes" : mes,
                "ano" : ano
              };
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'payroll_row.php',
    data: parametros,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      $('#id_hidden').val(response.codigoRac);
      $('#mes_hidden').val(response.mes);
      $('#ano_hidden').val(response.ano);

    }
  });
}
```

Bueno ojala a alguien le sirva. *Saludos!*